# Insert/find/update operator performance?

Tags: python, mongodb, performance, nosql

```
def test_find_update():
    db = Connection()
    db.drop_collection("test")
    db.test.insert({"x":1,"y":2})
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(1,10000):
        y = db.test.find_one()
    print db.test.find_one()
    print time.time()-start

    db.drop_collection("test")
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(1,10000):
        db.test.insert({"x":1,"y":2})
    print db.test.find_one()
    print time.time()-start

    db.drop_collection("test")
    db.test.insert({"x":1,"y":2})
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(1,10000):
        db.test.update({},{"$inc":{"x":1,"y":2}})
    print db.test.find_one()
    print time.time()-start
```

result:

```
{u'y': 2, u'x': 1, u'_id': ObjectId('4ffd159ae3f0f8103a000000')}
    **9.78821802139**
{u'y': 2, u'x': 1, u'_id': ObjectId('4ffd15a4e3f0f8103a000001')}
    **0.82381606102**
{u'y': 200000, u'x': 100000, u'_id': ObjectId('4ffd15a5e3f0f8103a002710')}
    **0.635884046555**
```

I think find operator may be so cheap, but it is opposite to my assumption.
Can anyone tell me why find operator is so time consuming?

Comment: What are you trying to test? Non-indexed finds versus fire-and-forget writes? 10k documents in a single query? This doesn't sound like a particularly informative test since it has no relation with anything you'd do in production systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you issue a insert or update call from PyMongo it will not wait for a reply from the server, but instead it will return immediatly. If you change your code so that the update and insert call look like this:

```
db.test.insert({"x":1,"y":2}, safe=True)
db.test.update({},{"$inc":{"x":1,"y":2}}, safe=True)
```

It will take a lot longer:

```
{u'y': 2, u'x': 1, u'_id': ObjectId('4ffd1d8d29277b1606000000')}
 2.05725502968
{u'y': 2, u'x': 1, u'_id': ObjectId('4ffd1d8f29277b1606000001')}
 1.98976802826
{u'y': 20000, u'x': 10000, u'_id': ObjectId('4ffd1d9129277b1606002710')}
 1.96105003357
```

For reference see the docs on [pymongo.collection](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html).

Edit: I'm not sure what you are trying to test here, because in real life this situation would probablt not occur. If you find yourself sequentially find()'ing 10000 documents you should probably consider a batch operation, or another DB schema. Maybe a bit of denormalization can help you out.

Comment: Not to mention that the recorded query time is only 0.97 milliseconds *per query*. That's reasonably fast, especially when you consider that a significant portion of that time is probably network.